# How to create link or match across dataframes in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, hyperlink

I'm exporting two data frames, `df1` in Sheet1 and `df2` in Sheet2 through R script.

In sheet1, when I click any value in column `Shipmode` (for ex: First class) it should automatically highlight all rows in sheet2 which has value "First class" in the `Shipmode_Cust` column. The original dataset has 10k rows and 25 columns. Any options to implement this?

Sample dataset:

**df1:**

[image]

**df2:**

[image]

I tried the code below but it works only for a single click:

```r
wb11 <- createWorkbook() 
createSheet(wb11, "Sheet1")
createSheet(wb11, "Sheet2")
createSheet(wb11, "Sheet3")

rows <- createRow(sheet2) 
cells <- createCell(rows) 
setCellValue(cells[[1,1]], "To Other File") 
addHyperlink(cells[[1,1]],sprintf("file:///%s#%s!%s", normalizePath(tf11, "/"), names(getSheets(wb11))[2], "B2"), "FILE") 

saveWorkbook(wb11, tf11 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))
```

Comment: It sounds like you have some excel-functionality in mind which you want to implement via R. It would be helpful to know *how* you expect this to look in the excel-file when asking how to get R to do that (or if this is possible). The excel-function (click on value to highlight rows with same value) sounds like it may require VBA. So is your question how to implement VBA functions when creating excel files in R? Do you know already how to achieve this functionality in excel?

Comment: Hi, It is similar to the pivot we use in Excel. I tried the same in R but it wasn't successful. If I can have a Pivot table, thereby if I click on its data it would automatically move to the corresponding source data.

Comment: Any updates for this request?